# Testing jQuery .hide() and .show() separated by alert: div not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

Here is extremely basic code:

```
$('.myDiv').click(function() {

    $('.anotherDiv').hide();
    alert('pause the ui');
    $('.anotherDiv').show();
});
```

When I do the above, and the alert shows, the `.anotherDiv` still shows.  I am expecting it to be hidden.

If I remove the line: `$('.anotherDiv').show();` then that div does hide.  So I know that jQuery knows his div exists.

I am expecting an alert to pause the UI before it re-shows the div.  Is this not how JavaScript/jQuery works?

Comment: I think this is actually browser-dependent. You can't really depend on anything being rendered until you return from Javascript to the main event loop.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting, I am only testing in Chrome

Answer (score 1):

`.hide` can take a callback to be run after the element has been hidden:

```
$('.myDiv').click(function() {
    $('.anotherDiv').hide(function() {
          alert('pause the ui');
          $('.anotherDiv').show();
    });
});
```

The issue is basically that, although the element has been told to hide itself, the browser hasn't repainted, and the alert halts all other execution.

Comment: So it really is hiding then in a real life situation?  If I am doing heavy lifting in-between the two show/hide lines, I can count on it being hidden?  Nice solution by the way, I may use that.  Let me test first.

Comment: It is being told to hide.  If it gets told not to hide before it repaints, then it won't ever actually get hidden (unless you use the callback to have it wait until it has actually been hidden).

Comment: $(selector).hide(speed,easing,callback) - don't forget speed and easing when using a callback

Answer (score 0):

As [Barmar says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47063822/testing-jquery-hide-and-show-separated-by-alert-div-not-hiding#comment81075817_47063822), you can force repainting by returning from the function. You are able to do so using `setTimeout`, like this:

```
$('.myDiv').click(function() {
    $('.anotherDiv').hide();
    setTimeout(
        function(){
            alert('pause the ui');
            $('.anotherDiv').show();
        },
        0
    );
});
```